# How were books made before the printing press?

Tags: book, handwriting

How were books made before the printing press, did writer first write on each single paper and than bound all papers in book or they wrote directly in book?
Books are wrote in cursive?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about writing as defined in the help center.

Comment: [The Wikipedia article on the history of books](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_books) should answer your question. Please use your search engine of choice if you are interested in the history of writing and publishing. This site is to help writers writing today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the surviving books created before the printing press were written on individual pages then bound into a [manuscript](https://www.nga.gov/conservation/paper/manuscript-project.html). Many were copied from scrolls, translating the knowledge of the ancient world into   the lingua franca of the day.

Mostly, they used block lettering, but some used cursive.  For instance, Davinci’s [notebooks](https://www.vam.ac.uk/articles/leonardo-da-vincis-notebooks) are cursive.  Leonardo wrote on loose papers that were bound into notebooks after his death.

Comment: Da Vinci's notebooks were personal notes, weren't they? Cursive was generally used for personal stuff, letters and such, since the times of ancient Rome. By the way, Leonardo was born (only a handful of years, but still) after Guttenberg constructed his press using movable type, and lived all his life in a world where printed books were a thing already.

Comment: @Divizna, yes, the Da Vinci's notebooks were his papers, presumably written backward to frustrate anyone trying to steal his ideas. I thought he predated Guttenberg. Thanks for sharing that observation.

Comment: Didn't predate Guttenberg, as I'm sure you've looked up too, it's Guttenberg's press - 1440 or so, Leonardo's life - 1452-1519. And I thought he wrote backwards simply because it was more comfortable for him that way when writing with left hand.